# Error BFProj2.Models.ContextModel does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges' what am I missing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I keep getting this error, usually it has something to do with a using statement, but I think I might have messed something up or there is a using statement that I missed. And now I don't know what it is. Seen other people with the same question but finding out what using statement to use. Tried every Entity Framework statement but no other ones seem to be needed.

**'BFProj2.Models.ContextModel' does not contain a definition for 'SaveChanges' and no extension method 'SaveChanges' accepting a first argument of type 'BFProj2.Models.ContextModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BFProj2.DAL;



namespace BFProj2.DAL
{
    [Table("DataPlacer")]
    public partial class DataPlacer : IEntity
    {
        public int csvId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string csvcolumn { get; set; }
    }

    public class IEntity
    {
        public int Id;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using BFProj2.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;


namespace BFProj2.DAL
{

    public class DCResultsRepository : IRepository<DataPlacer>
    {

        ContextModel _DataPlacerContext;

        public DCResultsRepository()
        {
            _DataPlacerContext = new ContextModel();
        }

        public IEnumerable<DataPlacer> List
        {
            get
            {
                return _DataPlacerContext.DataPlacer;
            }
        }

        public void Add(DataPlacer entity)
        {
            //TODO: Saknas usingsats som gör att SaveChanges inte fungerar.
            _DataPlacerContext.DataPlacer.Add(entity);
            _DataPlacerContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Delete(DataPlacer entity)
        {
            _DataPlacerContext.DataPlacer.Remove(entity);
            _DataPlacerContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public void Update(DataPlacer entity)
        {
            _DataPlacerContext.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            _DataPlacerContext.SaveChanges();
        }

        public DataPlacer FindById(int Id)
        {
            var result = (from r in _DataPlacerContext.DataPlacer 
                          where r.Id == Id 
                          select r).FirstOrDefault();
            return result;
        }
}
```

IRepository:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;

namespace BFProj2.DAL
{
    interface IRepository<T> where T:IEntity
    {

        IEnumerable<T> List { get; }
        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        T FindById(int Id);

    }
```

Model:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace BFProj2.Models
{
public class ContextModel
    {
        //public object _DataPlacerContext { get; set; }

        public List<DAL.DataPlacer> DataPlacer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ContextModel` only has one property (`DataPlacer`). It does not have a method named `SaveChanges`!

Comment: How do I add a method for save changes, do I connect to SQL to save or can I keep it in the application without having to contact the database?

Comment: Looks like you are using EF. Just use the `SaveChanges()` method of your db context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to inherit from `DbContext` as shown below :-

```
public class ContextModel : DbContext
    {
        //public object _DataPlacerContext { get; set; }

        public List<DAL.DataPlacer> DataPlacer { get; set; }
    }
```

and make sure you have given reference of EntityFramework.dll in your project